# CloudKit query indices validity

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Doc says:

> WARNING Query indexes are updated asynchronously so they are not
>   guaranteed to be current. If you query for records that you recently
>   changed and not allow enough time for those changes to be processed,
>   the query results may be incorrect. The results may not contain the
>   correct records and the records may be out of order.

Valid query result is crucial for me. Looks like currently there is no other option than provide some time for changes to be processed. Is there amount of time considered safe? Is there any case where query is as reliable as fetch? I would like to avoid forward referencing (highly recommended by Apple).

Comment: "I would like to avoid forward referencing (highly recommended by Apple)." - I am aware that Apple recommend inverse references (to allow automatic deletion of related records) but I am not aware of a recommendation to avoid forward references, I.e. I would feel free to implement a forward reference in addition to the recommended inverse one.

Comment: WWDC14, session 231 from 26:20 and WWDC16, session 231 from 33:45. Implementing two-way reference is an option here, but in addition to handling conflicts, it's also a redundancy issue (likely leading to inconsistency if conflicts are not handled properly) so I better take my hands off this one.